# Android Google map API v2 suddenly stopped working in my app that was in the Play store

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-api-console

My app is in the Play store and was working fine when suddenly the Google map in the app stopped working. Its gets and error:

```
09-29 10:27:33.019: E/Google Maps Android API(20025): Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

I checked API Console settings and nothing is changed. Please can someone help me why Google maps stopped working in my App suddenly?

Someone please tell me that I am not the only one getting this "Authentication Issue" for Google maps. I got this error many times during the development of my App. It always appeared and disappeared suddenly for unknown reasons.

Comment: mines fine, i just looked at your question then checked, do you have any specific information on device or anything?

Comment: is there any possibility that you created a new release of the app with a new API key different from the key in the earlier releases of the app? can you please share your app's playstore link.

Comment: JRowan, I did not add any additional information as it does not work on any new device. However, the strange thing is that the application is still working on my HTC Desire HD. I did not change the API key or anything. Frankly I did not even open API console in last 3 months.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you manage to find out what the problem was?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue.At first, it all looked very frustrating **but then I found that I changed the system date**.The moment I restored it back to the current date, it all started working fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check is that the date and time on your phone is set correctly or not. If not, do not use automatically but set it manually. I just spent 4 hours getting frustrated over this and then I remembered I had noted it down somewhere in my notes, tried it - and it worked!